# Linux Apache Django video static file issue

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, static

Ubuntu 16.04, Apache, python 3.6 with django.

My view is serving up the path of a static video file to my template.  It was working fine running the manage.py dev server.  It was not working properly on the apache server.  I reloaded apache but still get:

"No video with supported format and MIME type found" message in Firefox.

Apache didn't have the full path, just a relative path from my django app.  So I passed the full path to the template.  I get the same error, dev and apache servers.  I grabbed the HTML out of the template and it works fine; the video played.

www-data has rwx all the way up to the file and the directories.  Not sure what is going on.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To simplify, I tried to display an image on an empty virtual host without django and still had the same issue.  Finally switched to a relative path and it worked.  

So instead of /var/www/test2.com/html_public/heart.png I put the file in html_public dir and used <img src="heart.png">.  html_public was the site config documentroot.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding following to `.htaccess` file

```
# MIME types for Video
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
AddType video/x-flv flv
```

Comment: Didn't work; let's try something simpler image file with no spaces.  Adding my code in just a few.

Comment: Firefox can open a file test.html with this just fine  <img src="/var/www/myproject/mediaserver/static/mediaserver/video/heart.png">

Comment: My template:  {% load static %}
<img src="/var/www/myproject/mediaserver/static/mediaserver/video/heart.png">

Comment: Apache config: Alias /media/ /var/www/myproject/mediaserver/static/mediaserver/video/
        <Directory /var/www/myproject/mediaserver/static/mediaserver/video/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

Comment: settings.py:  STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
'/var/www/myproject/mediaserver/static/mediaserver/video/',
)

Comment: .htaccess in the same path above:  AddType image/png .png

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

I tried to store my static files elsewhere (app_name/static/app_name) but it did not work.

First ran this code to collect the static files:

```
$python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then reloaded the server:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Then updated my template to point to the project static directory in settings.py:

```
{% load static %}

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="{% static "mediaserver/video/Baby Jack 2010.02.06.mp4" %}">
</video>
```